# How to upload an attachment to GitHub wiki?

Tags: github, wiki

I know how to reference it from wikis but where in GitHub site do I upload the attachment? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a programming Q&A website.

Comment: I don't think this is really a bad question to ask here. And you actually can do this: the wiki is a Git repo so you can clone it, add your attachments, then commit them.

Comment: I have nominated this for reopening. The Stack Overflow [scope](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) clearly includes "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: writing doc is part of programming, especially in a Github wiki. Voted for reopen. Btw @ron gives the answer.

Comment: You can link an image from your repository. See here: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-images-to-wikis/

Comment: 1. `New issue`, 2. drag your image to upload, 3. copy the link to your wiki.

Comment: I'm really not sure why this was closed as it's very applicable to programming due to the need for documentation.

In addition, there is a solution, if you checkout the wiki, add the files and then commit them, you can link them just fine. In my case I needed to add some example properties files, so I committed and pushed them then linked to them through [properties file](my-file.properties).

Comment: As mentioned by @Mr_and_Mrs_D , the answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045517/embedding-images-inside-a-github-wiki-gollum-repository/12453272#12453272 .  To summarize, clone the wiki, commit the files to a subdirectory, then link to them `[example.json](files/example.json)`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of Feburary 14th, 2022 [GitHub allows uploading images to Wiki pages by dragging files into the web editor](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-02-14-upload-images-to-wiki-pages/).

Caveat: Files will be uploaded to their *githubusercontent* bucket, not added to the git repository for the wiki.

---

Original post:

Just to answer it shortly: You can't. You have to upload your images somewhere else (like in a repository or on an image hoster) and link it

But I agree with @jstephenson

Comment: Since the beginning of this month, GitHub supports file uploads in issues https://github.com/blog/1347-issue-attachments

Comment: but that is only for commenting in "issues" no?

Comment: I just have a issue thread named Images that I upload to, then pull from that anytime I need one in my wiki.

Comment: Your answer is misleading see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438197/how-do-you-upload-an-attachment-to-github-wiki#comment19030025_9438197 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12453272/281545 please edit

Comment: See instructions for linking to it in a repository here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10414862/255961

Comment: Help can be found here: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-images-to-wikis/

Comment: Well a wiki is just a git repo so you can clone it to desktop, add your imaged and upload the repo again. You can access your images afterwards like: https://github.com/YOUR-NAME/YOUR_REPO/wiki/IMAGE.png

Comment: You can now drag and drop image file on wiki page in edit mode.  This is more up-to-date than Benny Code's link.  This question should be reopened.  https://github.blog/changelog/2022-02-14-upload-images-to-wiki-pages/

Comment: @ErikOstermueller I have added the link to the answer. Thanks for pointing to the update